# TypeScript: assign custom property on window object

Tags: typescript

I have a web extension that applies a custom object on the window object like:

```
window.extensionName // { method1: () => {} }
```

However in my TypeScript files, when I reference `window.extensionName`, I get this error:

```
Property 'extensionName' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

But it does in fact exist on the `window` object because it was added by the extension. How do I make TypeScript stop complaining about this?

And is there a way to specify the new object's type globally for my whole project so that TypeScript can use autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `declare var` to declare that `extensionName` exists on `globalThis` ([documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html)).

```
declare var extensionName: { method1: () => {} };

window.extensionName.method1 = () => {
  return {};
}
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8QA8AuIB2BnAlgPbYByUAtiAFzwDe8lGAFocAIw0AUAlPALwA+OgF94wgNwAoSQHd82YIRkA6dFjxFSFEMsYt2-eD35Dak+PDgYArjGwipwyUA)

Comment: I pasted your example in a `.tsx` file and got `Property 'extensionName' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'`

Comment: @sdfsdf, then can you update the question to show enough code to reproduce the issue? Preferably through a link like David and I have in our answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the definition of `Window` via [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

This does not produce an error:

```
interface Window {
  extensionName: {
    method1: () => {}
  }
}

window.extensionName.method1 = () => {
  return {};
}
```

TypeScript [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOqgCYHsDuyDeAUMshAB6QgDOwWIAcnALYQBcBxJyLYAFlhgCM7ABQBKZAF4AfAQC+nBQsI5MuAHTlKNOoxbqe-IVOTipsoiSgQwAVygh5AbkIKgA) demonstrating this technique.

Comment: I pasted your example in a `.tsx` file and got `Property 'extensionName' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.`